# Linq to Sql - Filter table result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL table :

```
Id  FirstName   LastName    DateTime
1   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:45:52.293
2   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:45:53.620
3   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.370
4   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.533
5   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.680
6   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.820
```

And one class and instance :

```
public class Cus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Last { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

List<Cus> o = new List<Cus>()
{
    new Cus()
    {
        Id = 1,
        First = "John",
        Last = "Doe"
    },
    new Cus()
    {
        Id = 2,
        First = "John",
        Last = "Doe"
    },
    new Cus()
    {
        Id = 3,
        First = "John",
        Last = "Doe"
    }
};
```

I use Linq To Sql class for get all record in my sql table. I do :

```
using(DataClassesDataContext Context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var Customers = Context.Customers.Where(x => x.Any(y => o. ????????;
}
```

But I want to take in my table only customer who is in `List<Cus>` (using `Id`)

How to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all the Id's from the `o` collection and use `Contains` method to filter out the Customers who's Id is in the user id collection we created.

```
//Get the Id's from o collection.
var userIds = o.Select(f=>f.Id);

//Get the customers who's id belongs to the above collection
var customers = yourDbContext.Customers.Where(x => userIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a list of IDs and using `Contains` may be the most effective approach since it can be translated to an `IN` clause in SQL:

```
List<int> ids = o.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

using(DataClassesDataContext Context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var Customers = Context.Customers.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
}
```